# Flutter - sqflite - How to store blob image to device and update the path to another column on Version update?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

#### Background

I have created an application and it is Live in Play Store. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.epix.warranty_manager

#### Issue

Initially, I have stored all the images in table columns as blob.

As of now, many users are facing the following issue

```
row too big to fit into cursorwindow requiredpos=0, totalrows=1
```

> Above is the error message from the flutter sqflite package.

#### Temp Fix ☑

As a temporary fix, whenever there is a catch I have removed that images column from the select query and returned the result.

#### Permanent Fix ✅

Need to remove the blob images from the table during version update and save it in the device storage and update the path to a new column.

### Migration File ❇

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

// v1 - testing
// v2 - main release
// v3 - added blob type for image
// v4 - fix for large image - store image in file instead of db

final Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then(
  (String path) {
    // void v4
    void _createV4(Batch batch) {
      batch.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE product(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price REAL, purchaseDate TEXT, warrantyPeriod TEXT, warrantyEndDate TEXT, internationalWarranty INTEGER, online INTEGER, purchasedAt TEXT, company TEXT, salesPerson TEXT, phone TEXT, email TEXT, website TEXT, notes TEXT, productImage BLOB, purchaseCopy BLOB, warrantyCopy BLOB, additionalImage BOLB, category TEXT, tags TEXT, profile TEXT, productImagePath TEXT, purchaseCopyPath TEXT, warrantyCopyPath TEXT, additionalImagePath TEXT)");
    }

    // upgrade from v1, v2 to v4
    void _upgradeFromV1ToV4(Batch batch) {
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD productImage BLOB END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD category TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD tags TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD profile TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD productImagePath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD purchaseCopyPath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD warrantyCopyPath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD additionalImagePath TEXT END');
    }

    // upgrade from v1, v2 to v4
    void _upgradeFromV2ToV4(Batch batch) {
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD productImagePath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD purchaseCopyPath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD warrantyCopyPath TEXT END');
      batch.execute('ALTER TABLE product ADD additionalImagePath TEXT END');
    }

    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'product.db'),
      version: 4,
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        var batch = db.batch();
        _createV4(batch);
        await batch.commit(continueOnError: true);
      },
      onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) async {
        var batch = db.batch();
        if (oldVersion == 1 || oldVersion == 2) {
          _upgradeFromV1ToV4(batch);
        } else if (oldVersion == 3) {
          _upgradeFromV2ToV4(batch);
        }
        await batch.commit(continueOnError: true);
      },
      onDowngrade: onDatabaseDowngradeDelete,
    );
  },
);
```

#### Problem

Since the version update happens in batch, I am not able to get results out of the batch.

Since there is 4 image column in each row, I am not able to find out which images is larger is size.

#### Help

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

#### Source Code ‍

Github: https://github.com/Aravin/WarrantyManager